# geometrical and algebraic interpretation of $i$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, linear-transformations

Years ago I asked for an explanation about $i$ and what its meaning was, why $i$ was invented in the first place without even considering the usual rules for "interfacing" real and complex numbers on the $x,y$ plane .

The answer that I got was really terse and cryptic, it was something along the lines of

> $i$ is a device that helps you when commuting

I use linear algebra rarely and that "answer" wasn't a real answer, certainly wasn't really enlightening and/or exhaustive .

$i$ got more interesting, at least for me, when I tried to solve one of the simplest equations in math which is the quadratic that describes the $x$ and $y$ of a circle

$$x^2+y^2=1$$

the 4 possible solutions of this equation, for me, are a more viable explanation of what $i$ is .

But at this point my question is a double question :

- What kind of operation is this "commutation" ? Is it a linear transformation ? it has some specific properties and mathematician have a clear definition of what it is ?
- with a good definition of the commutation, what is the subject, the operand if you will, in the case of $i$ ? is it the origin $0,0$ ?

Can someone explain this to me on a geometric level with linear transformations ?

I have trouble defining this, for example $i$ doesn't show a linear behaviour, it doesn't look like this "commutation" is a linear transformation, or a transformation that I alread know of any sort .

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what your answer means either, and the person probably had a specific example in mind. Historically, $i$ was invented as a formal object to solve cubic equations. People found that they could not extract the roots of cubics (even the real ones) without encountering the object $\sqrt{-1}$. Of course they didn't have any formalism for really dealing with this object back then, but it was a necessary crutch. The whole modern view of $\mathbb{C}$ as a field extension came much later.

Comment: The history is very interesting. Non-real complex numbers were first explored by Bombelli, because they come up naturally in the Cardano procedure for finding the roots of a cubic, even when the roots of the cubic are all real.

Comment: You may find [this article](https://eva.fing.edu.uy/pluginfile.php/88686/mod_resource/content/1/Thinking_the_Unthinkable__the_Story_of_C.pdf) by Israel Kleiner interesting.

Comment: The interpretation of $\mathbb{C}$ as the real plane happened much later than the introduction of $i$ (which was indeed made up purely for solving equations, since it can be proved that for some equations, even when all the roots are real you can't express them by radicals without using complex numbers).

Comment: Also not sure what is meant by "commuting". But if you want to think in terms of linear maps of the plane $\Bbb{R}^2$, think of a complex number $z = x+iy$ as a vector $\vec{v} = (x,y)$. Then multiplication by $i$ is just rotation by 90 degrees counterclockwise. That is, you can think of it geometrically as "$iz$" $= \left( \begin{array}{cc}0&-1\\1&0\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y\end{array}\right)$.

Comment: I apologize for being super late, but I took my time to read some articles in the spare time, especially the ones being listed in your comments, and I still think there something that is "non-linear" about $i$ but I'm still not grasping a good understanding about what and why . If you would like to write an answer with more insights you are welcome to do so. Thanks .